# Regarding usage of hyphens for numbers with preposition

Tags: hyphenation

Here are few examples of hyphen usage I found (albeit on internet) for numbers with preposition in between. At the same time I find these without hyphens in similar usage.

1. **#-for-#**

   - [Barry] "Bonds went **3-for-4** and scored three times" [ESPN](https://www.espn.co.uk/mlb/recap?gameId=220804123)
   - [Barry] "Bonds went **3 for 4** and scored three times" [WashingtonPost](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/sports/2002/08/05/bondss-drive-for-600-speeds-up-at-pnc/cee51d74-23cd-413e-b8ae-5cce1ef43a08/?utm_term=.5e65a99a2a2f)
2. **#-of-#**

   - "The forward posted 12 points on 5-for-9 shooting from the floor and a solid **2-of-5** behind the arc." [NBA](https://www.nba.com/knicks/knicks-face-winslows-heat-second-summer-league-outing)
   - [Damion] "Lee went **2 of 6** from 3-point range." [NYTimes](https://nytimes.stats.com/nba/playerstats.asp?id=5733)
3. **#-to-#**

   - "Andover Hall is the early favorite at **2-to-1** odds, ..." [NYTimes](https://www.nytimes.com/2002/08/03/sports/harness-racing-andover-hall-the-favorite-for-the-77th-hambletonian.html)
   - "For instance the latest betting lines for UFC Fight Night in Cincinnati have instilled the favorite at **2 to 1** odds." [Fox](https://www.foxsports.com/stories/other/matt-brown-is-a-2-to-1-underdog-to-erick-silva-what)

So my question is, are their any rules of hyphen usage for numbers that are glued together with a preposition? **If there is a rule, then a reference to the rule will be greatly appreciated.**

The only rule that seems to exist is ... when it is used to describe a noun and the description is before the noun with the unit involved always in singular form (e.g. inch) like so.

- **#-by-#-unit**

  - "Line the bottom and sides of a **13-by-9-inch** cake pan with foil, ..." [LATimes](https://www.latimes.com/recipe/creamy-labneh-lemon-bars)

I believe **#-by-#-unit** case falls under **Rule 4** of [**The Blue Book of Grammar and Punctuation: Hyphens**](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp) but I wonder if anyone will raise an eyebrow if the above example was written without hyphens like: "Line the bottom and sides of a **13 by 9 inch** cake pan with foil.

Comment: I will raise that eyebrow for 'a 13 by 9 inch cake pan'.

Comment: I think it's a case-by-case thing and each should be asked separately: dimensions, odds, and sports statistics all have their own conventions.

Comment: @Řídící on Amazon there are a lot of cases of "12 by 12 inch" (and "12 by 12-Inch" or "12 by 12 inches"). Not the best place for good grammar, but certainly one with lots of examples.

Comment: @StuartF: Although I understand it is case-by-case, for each of the above (#-for-#, #-of--#, #-to-#), each case is in similar usage context (sports stats, sports stats, odds respectively). Is there a right vs wrong or a preferred way of writing specifically for the examples that I've given above? The examples I used are taken from outlets where I presume there are designated people within the organization to check grammar and styles. I am kind of confused why it is inconsistent when usage seems to be the same (for the above example that I've given).